# entityframework inner join

Tags: c#, linq, entity

I am trying to join between customers,orders,orderdetails and products

I used the following to generate an inner join query

```
IQueryable<Customer> CustomerList = ent.Customer
                                     .Include("orders").Include("orders.orderdetails")
                                      .include(orders.orderdetails.products)
```

I need to generate an inner join with these tables so that i can check surname and firstname in where clause but it is generating left outer join.

How to generate an inner join with these tables

thanks

Comment: If you set LazyLoadingEnabled to true, you will not need to do all those includes. Makes it simpler. However, with big data, lazy loading could be a lot slower.

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = from OrdersDetails od in ent.OrdersDetails
            select new {
                od.Orders.Customers.FirtsName,
                od.Orders.OrderDate,
                ....
            }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
            var v = from en in context.Entity
                let leftouter = (from pa in en.PostalAddress
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     pa.PostalAddressID
                                 }).FirstOrDefault()
                select new
                {
                    EntityID = en.EntityID,
                    PostalAddressID = (Guid?)leftouter.PostalAddressID,
                };
```

refered from http://geekswithblogs.net/SudheersBlog/archive/2009/06/11/132758.aspx